# Internet recovery mode cannot connect to wpa2 network

Tags: recovery

As above

I've reached the internet recovery screen and entered the correct password for the wpa2 network but all I have is the network selection drop down and a spinning globe with no loading bar.

What can I do to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: cycle the router on/off

Answer (score 1):

Problem was troubleshooted and resolved as a DHCP error.

A static IP address had been assigned to the windows partition for my mac. This cloned mutltiple assigned addresses and shut out other devices.

Solution : removing the staticly assigned ip address resolved the issue.